# Find a specific critical point from set of equations for $f(x,y) = xy(12-3x-4y)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

I'm having trouble finding a specific critical point from set of equations for $f(x,y) = xy(12-3x-4y)$. In particular it is the critical point $(\frac{4}{3},1)$

Calculating the first order derivatives for $x$ and $y$ we get the set of equations:

$$\partial_{x}f = y(12-6x-4y) = 0 \\ \partial_{y}f = x(12-3x-8y) = 0$$

Could somebody assist me in solving for this specific critical point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously $(x,y)=(0,0)$ its a critical point, so, suppose that $x\neq0$ and that $y\neq0$. Hence, 
$$y(12-6x-4y)=0 \textrm{ implies } 12-6x-4y=0$$
and similarly $12-3x-8y=0$ from the second equation. It follows that the *unique* solution to the system of equations
$$\left\{\begin{align}
-6x-4y&=-12 \\
-3x-8y&=-12
\end{align}\right.$$
is $(x,y) = \big(\tfrac43,1\big)$.

Comment: Thank you sir....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stream plot:

[image]

$$(0,3), (4/3,1), (4,0), (0,0)$$ marked, each of which you can analyze for the value of the derivatives (and second derivatives).

Comment: quick question. How do you embed graphics such as this into solutions. Also thank you for taking the time to produce this. Shocked (and honored) that a man of such high accomplishments still has time for us meagre plebs of the math world...

Comment: @dc3rd:  Copy your plot to your computer clipboard, then while writing/editing your solution click on the "insert graphics" icon and paste...  (Oh... and thanks for your compliment... but I sometimes need a break from my current very big writing project, and solving such math problems is a wonderful and relaxing diversion...)